# Why am I getting a ">: contract violation, expected: real? given ', 3 error"?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to make a function that gets the max value from a list by hand and when I run it it keeps giving me a contract violation error and I can't figure out why.

```
(define (get_max list)
  ;if only one element left return that element
  (if (null? (cdr list))
      (car list)
  ;if second element is larger than first then loop again without first element, else loop again subtracting second element from list
  (if (> (car (cdr list)) (car list))
      (get_max (cdr list)) (get_max (cons (car list) (cdr(cdr list))))
  )))

;call function
(get_max '(5, 3, 8, 2))
```

Comment: The problem is a typo: `(get_max '(5, 3, 8, 2))`. Don't put commas in lists in lisps. Also, wrt lisp style: prefer `kebab-case` to `snake_case`, don't put parentheses on separate lines, don't run comments out off of the edge of a terminal window, and indent your forms properly to make the code easier to read.

Comment: Oh, I feel dumb. This was indeed the problem and it is working correctly now, thank you.